# UnitTest and Database

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, doctrine-orm, phpunit

I would like to make some unittest for my application. As is my first time managing with PHPUnit (and unittest more in general) I would like to have an advice.

First, let's say that I have this class

```
class LodgingManager
{
    private $session;
    private $entity_manager;

        public function __construct(Session $session, EntityManager $em)
        {
            $this->session = $session;
            $this->entity_manager = $em;
        }

        public function loadLodgingList()
        {
            //If I've already fetched lodgings from db, use the session one.
            //Everytime a lodging is added, session is refreshed
            $lodging_list = $this->session->get('lodging_list');
            if (!$lodging_list) {
                $lodging_repo = $this->entity_manager->getRepository('KoobiBookingEngineBundle:Lodging');
                $lodging_list = $lodging_repo->getAllForList();

                $this->session->set('lodging_list', $lodging_list);
            }

            return $lodging_list;
        } 
        [...]
    }
```

This is a simple and silly method but, starting from here to me seems quite useful as code isn't to much complex to follow. As everyone can see I use a custom DQL method that helps me to retrieve some entities and place them into session.

I've created a test database with some dummy data and I would to test them.

As far as i know Doctrine's EntityManager has a protected `__construct()` method. This means that you can't use a "real" EntityManager but you need to use a mock one. Same consideration could be done for Repository and so on.

So the code I've producted is the following

```
class LodgingManagerTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    const LODGING_CLASS = 'KoobiBookingEngineBundle:Lodging';

    /** @var LodgingManager */
    protected $lodging_manager;
    /** @var \PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject */
    protected $em;
    /** @var \PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject */
    protected $repository;
    /** @var \PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject */
    protected $session;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $lodging_array_collection = new ArrayCollection();
        $lodging = $this->getMock('Koobi\BookingEngineBundle\Entity\Lodging');
        $lodging_array_collection->add($lodging);

        $repository = $this->getMockBuilder('Koobi\BookingEngineBundle\Repository\LodgingRepository')
            ->disableOriginalconstructor()
            ->getMock();
        $repository->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getAllForList')
            ->will($this->returnValue($lodging_array_collection));
        $this->repository = $repository;

        $em = $this->getMockBuilder('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager')
            ->disableOriginalconstructor()
            ->getMock();
        $em->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getRepository')
            ->with($this->equalTo(static::LODGING_CLASS))
            ->will($this->returnValue($repository));
        $this->em = $em;

        $this->session = new Session(new MockArraySessionStorage());

        $this->lodging_manager = $this->createLodgingManager($this->session, $this->em);
    }

    public function testLoadLodgingList()
    {
        $lodging_list = $this->lodging_manager->loadLodgingList();
        $this->assertCount(1, $lodging_list);

    }
}
```

Every object of test is a mocked one (except for Lodging that is a "real" one). But to me this test is pretty useless as I can't load real entities from database.

I perfectly know that this kind of test is a silly one, but I can easily imagine some other complex one that need **real** objects.

So, asking to expert users, what's your opinion about? How can I procede to make more relevant and appropriate tests?

Comment: instead of a unit test, that work in an isolated context, you should make a functional test, with data loaded via fixtures, but you must construct this fixtures by yourself, so yes, in particular situation you should do a functional test of your repository method (or your services). my two cents

Comment: @Matteo: thank you for your answer. I will definitely do even functional tests, but as far as I know, if you want a 100% (or at least if you try to) of cases covered, you should also make unit-test(s). I'm I wrong? Moreover to you could be a good situation maybe to test repository method directly whilst use "dummy" one for manager? In that case I could have 100% of case covered for this method.

Comment: sometime working with fixture is an headache: you must maintain them and you must build the relation and so on. Usually i do unit test when i have a complex business logic, I a minimum set of functional test with the controller (testing only the response code and not based on the DOM page element) and when i'm not really confident with my custom repo method i do a functional test also. This is only my opinion, i'm a really enjoyed TDD but... waiting for an answer from a very expert guy! Sorry for my very long comment,

Comment: @Matteo: Better more words than less. I'm a very beginner of unit/function test(s) so everyone pointing me to right direction is well accepted! :) However your point of view is pretty clear and I agree with you. Of course this example, as I told before, is just to immerse myself into testing framework logic.

Comment: Welcome aboard! Regard your example, i suggest you to do a functional test of the custom repo method, and do your unit test of the service, i usually mock the session also, finally, if in your service use only one repo, don't inject the entire entity manager but only the repository see [here](http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2014/05/inject-a-repository-instead-of-an-entity-manager/) .
Finally i would suggest you to take a look at [Phake](http://phake.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction.html) for mock object less verbose and more coincisive (yes is not the only or the best....)

Comment: @Matteo: Thank you for this advice. I will take a look to Phake. BTW my Manager use EntityManager for other operation that will involve persist(), flush() and so on so thank you for your suggestion but is perfectly fine as it is :)

Answer (score 2):

you should refactor you code to separate 'simple, stupid' dao from everything else (session management and business logic). then divide your tests into 2 or 3 groups.

1. unit tests: testing components in isolation from environment (also from database). in this tests you mock your database (entityManager, repositories, however it's called in your technology) and you check if those mocks are being called as expected
2. database tests: you use your **real** entityManager, repositories and mysql/oracle/whatever to test if your sql/orm code is working correctly. you are testing only your database code without any business logic or session management
3. end-to-end tests. you start whole application and simulate users clicking web interface

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you should do:

1. **unit testing** your services for check that the "business logic" are done well, the flow of the code is correct and so on...
2. **functional test** some component (custom repository method or specific
   services) with database fixture you make (the side effect is that
   you must maintain them and you must build the relation and so on)
3. **functional test** your controller only minimal check (HTTP response code) possibly don't check about the DOM element of the page.

Hope this help